# How to retain the fragment once the App got destroyed or closed

Tags: android, fragment, retain

I am trying to develop an app whose requirement is to retain the Tab even after closing the app or suddenly if the app gets destroyed in run time

My app has 3 tabs,I am adding items in secondtab "CheckList"
When ever i close my app second tab its again with New page instead of items added previously

I want my app to be same as picture 2 even after closing the app,But it seems everytime i close the app tab appears to be like picture 1

Picture 1  https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSgTZ.png

Picture 2 https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUim4.png

Psuedo Code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    ViewPager mViewPager;
    public Fragment fragment;
    private FragmentActivity myContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        View viewActionBar = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.titlebar, null);
        ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(//Center the textview in the ActionBar !
                ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                );
        TextView textviewTitle = (TextView) viewActionBar.findViewById(R.id.mytext);
        textviewTitle.setText("Application");
        actionBar.setCustomView(viewActionBar, params);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);


        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i)).setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch(position){
                case 0:
                    fragment = new FirstTab();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new SecondTab();

                    break;
                case 2:
                    fragment = new ThirdTab();

            }
            return fragment;
        }
```

Second Tab Code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        if(view==null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);
// retain this fragment


            bt = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview3);
            tl = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.table);


          public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    }
```

I am stuck here,Can you please tell me how do i save this Tab with the above method and
How to retain?

I have seen Few answers relates to retaining the fragment but it did not solved my problem

I am new to android Development,Please try to help to resolve this problem

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retain a `Fragment` instance.

Instead, you should persist & restore the `Fragment`s state. (e.g. using `SharedPreferences`)